# Why clang causes error?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

There's 3 files:

`MyClass.h` :

```
#ifndef LABEL
#define LABEL

class MyClass {
public:
    std::string toStr() const;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const MyClass&);
};

#endif
```

`MyClass.cpp` :

```
#include <string>
#include "MyClass.h"

std::string MyClass::toStr() const {
    std::string str = "some text";
    return str;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyClass& obj) {
    return os << obj.toStr();
}
```

`main.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
    MyClass a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling them with GCC 5.1 (`g++-5 main.cpp BigInteger.cpp -std=c++11`) does not causes errors but when compiling with clang (`clang++ main.cpp BigInteger.cpp -std=c++11`) it produces the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, MyClass const&) in BigInteger-a5ec56.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's wrong?

P.S. OS X Yosemite. Clang version:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Your `MyClass.h` header should include `<string>` itself. However, that's not why you're getting linking errors.

Comment: You are not including `<iostream>` in `MyClass.h` as well.

Comment: most likely your clang uses the gcc 5.1 headers, but the old libstdc++. Post the results of the following commands: `clang  -v -x c++ /dev/null -fsyntax-only` and `ldd executable` where executable is an executable compiled with clang++ (just an empty main, no includes)

Comment: These are linker errors, so the problem is with your clang setup, not with your code.

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not edited into the question. (Another question is why g++ accepts it.)

Comment: @bolov I have faced the issue you described - what is the solution? How can I make clang++ to refer to clang provided headers? ex: <iostream>